# secondary CustomUserStore in deployment.toml in wso2

Tags: wso2-identity-server

How to write secondary CustomUserStoreManager i deployment.toml in wso2is 5.9, if i write

```
[user_store]
type = "read_write_ldap"
connection_url = "ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}"
connection_name = "uid=admin,ou=system"
connection_password = "admin"
base_dn = "dc=wso2,dc=org"      #refers the base dn on which the user and group search bases will be generated
class="com.wso2.custom.usermgt.CustomUserStoreManager"
```

then I cant login as admin/admin , please advice the same , I have placed a text_com.xml in userstore directory as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserStoreManager class="com.wso2.custom.usermgt.CustomUserStoreManager">
<Property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2</Property>
<Property name="userName">root</Property>
<Property encrypted="true" name="password">subhash123</Property>
<Property name="driverName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Property>
<Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property> .......................................
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the documentation in [1] on how to write a CustomUserStoreManager in WSO2 IS 5.9.0.

[1] - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager

Comment: a)I added test_com.xml inside wso2is-5.9.0\repository\deployment\server\userstores similar to user_mgm.xml ., havent made any change deployment.toml.
b)Then started the server, . then did as told, above, i dont see anything under Secondary UserStore, :(

Comment: This link is is for Primary CustomUserStoreManager not for the Secondary CustomUserStoreManager, 
Regds,
Subhash

Comment: @Subhash, the format of the user-mgt.xml and test_com.xml are same. So use the management console to create the secondary user store

Answer (score 0):

As per your initial description, I assume that your requirement should be to add a secondary user store that uses a custom User store manager class. In that case if your custom user store manager is properly activated by adding the  text_com.xml to repository/deployment/server/userstores you did the right thing.

But adding the class property under [user_store] tag in the deployment.toml is not relevant to achieve your requirement. That configuration refers to the primary user store, If you need your primary user store to use that custom user store manager it is okay to add that configuration. Then if you were unable to log in using admin/admin there should be an issue in your custom user store manager.

One thing you can do is

1. Log in to the management console and click list in User Stores sub-menu under the Configure menu.
2. Click Add under User Stores to add a Secondary User Store.
3. Check whether your custom user store is listed or not.

If it is listed check the code there must be an issue in authenticating.

Comment: I dont want to change anything with respect to primary userstore, i am trying to add secondary userstore in to the system, and i need primary as well. 
So when I add test_com.xml to the userstore directory, after i log in as admin/admin, i shud be able to see the list of secondary users, which isnt happening as of now :( . 
I tried adding the class to the deployment.ytomy but it affects the primary userstore which is wrong for my usecase.

Comment: Have you tried adding the secondary user store from the management console not by adding xml file?

Comment: You can start a new question with your custom user store code pointed

Comment: can add the secondary userstore, and even the users will be listed from my custom table, but am unable to login using those users, logged in as domain/user-password doesnt login in i get
<code>[2020-02-10 16:24:52,198] [28a1f2e1-d6f1-4f9c-850f-0855a20f0bdb] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} - System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION
<code> error,
I created a internal role and gave all permissions and assigned users to new iternal role, still i get this error, also changed to PLAIN_TEXT .

Comment: am not getting any error as such , but here is what I have done, plz follow this link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60162072/config-issues-with-wso2is-5-9-customuserstoremanager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207562/discussion-between-subhash-and-buddhima-udaranga).

Comment: am badly stuck with [2020-02-20 18:44:48,886] [408113e6-212a-4aa3-8462-1d1edaaf493a] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} - System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION, I can view the custom user store and also users from the customtable, but unable to login, the complete code is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276534/unable-to-login-as-secondary-custom-user-manager-in-wso2-is-5-9 .

Answer (score 0):

This `[user_store]` config in deployment.toml file is used only for **primary userstore** configuration.

Since you have pointed `class="com.wso2.custom.usermgt.CustomUserStoreManager"`  in the primary userstore config, it won't use the default ReadWriteLdap Userstore Manager. If you are using the default ReadWrite Ldap as primary userstore, you can remove `class="com.wso2.custom.usermgt.CustomUserStoreManager"` from the deployment.toml file.  It is not necessary to point to the class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager" in user_store configs, if you are using the default readwrite ldap. This class will be infered from the [infer.json](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.5.x/distribution/kernel/carbon-home/repository/resources/conf/infer.json#L47) file based on the `type` used in the `[user_store]`

If you want to configure a **secondary userstore**, you can configure it via **management console** or you can **deploy it manually into /repository/deployment/server/ userstores directory**. Please follow this documentation to configure secondary userstore: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-secondary-user-stores/. Once you deploy the custom userstore manager, you can create the secondary userstore.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to modify the template in your setup you can do it this way:

1. Open the template file : `/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml.j2`
2. Add the following code block just below the primary user store block :

```
        {% for custom_user_store in custom_secondary_user_store %}
            <UserStoreManager class="{{custom_user_store.class}}">
                {% for property_name,property_value in custom_user_store.properties.items() %}
                <Property name="{{property_name}}">{{property_value}}</Property>
                {% endfor %}
            </UserStoreManager>
        {% endfor %}
```

3. in your deployment.toml, add your properties as follows :

```
    [[custom_secondary_user_store]]
    class = "com.owsome.code.MyCustomUserStore"
    properties.TenantManager = "org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager"
    properties.ReadOnly = false
    properties.ReadGroups = true
    properties.WriteGroups = true
    properties.UsernameJavaRegEx = "^[\S]{3,30}$"
```