# unable to login as secondary custom user manager in wso2 IS 5.9

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

in WSO2 IS 5.9,
a)i created a CustomeruserStoreManager and placed in drop-ins and along with mysql driver i lib lib folder,
b)I cud see the users from my custom usertable, created a internal and gave all permissions and assigned the 2 users test.com/dinuka and test.com.malinda to new role created.
c)In the login page i can login as admin/admin but unable to login as test.com/dinuka-dinuka, I get the error as

```
[2020-02-18 11:03:36,781] [cf46aae7-eb2b-4eeb-9683-e7adbbba5c1f] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} - System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION
```

I have disabled the claims as well,,

```
public class CustomUserStoreConstants {


    //Properties for Read Active Directory User Store Manager
    public static final ArrayList<Property> CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES = new ArrayList<Property>();
    public static final ArrayList<Property> CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES = new ArrayList<Property>();
    public static final ArrayList<Property> CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES = new ArrayList<Property>();


    static {

        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.DRIVER_NAME, "Driver Name", "", "Full qualified driver name");
        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.URL,"Connection URL", "", "URL of the user store database");
        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.USER_NAME, "User Name","", "Username for the database");
        setMandatoryProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.PASSWORD, "Password","", "Password for the database");

        setProperty(UserStoreConfigConstants.disabled,"Disabled", "false", UserStoreConfigConstants.disabledDescription);

        setProperty("ReadOnly","Read Only", "true", "Indicates whether the user store of this realm operates in the user read only mode or not");
        setProperty(UserStoreConfigConstants.SCIMEnabled,"SCIM Enabled", "false", UserStoreConfigConstants.SCIMEnabledDescription);




        //Advanced Properties (No descriptions added for each property)
        setAdvancedProperty("SelectUserSQL","Select User SQL", "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_DATA WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME=?", "");
        setAdvancedProperty("UserFilterSQL","User Filter SQL", "SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME FROM CUSTOMER_DATA WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME LIKE ?  ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID", "");
        setAdvancedProperty("ClaimOperationsSupported","Claim Operations Supported","false","");


    }


    private static void setProperty(String name, String displayName, String value, String description) {
        Property property = new Property(name, value, displayName + "#" +description, null);
        CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES.add(property);

    }

    private static void setMandatoryProperty(String name, String displayName, String value, String description) {
        Property property = new Property(name, value, displayName + "#" +description, null);
        CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES.add(property);

    }

    private static void setAdvancedProperty(String name, String displayName, String value, String description) {
        Property property = new Property(name, value, displayName + "#" +description, null);
        CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES.add(property);

    }

}


public class CustomUserStoreManager extends JDBCUserStoreManager {


    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomUserStoreManager.class);

    public CustomUserStoreManager() {
    }

    public CustomUserStoreManager(org.wso2.carbon.user.api.RealmConfiguration realmConfig,
                                  Map<String, Object> properties,
                                  ClaimManager claimManager,
                                  ProfileConfigurationManager profileManager,
                                  UserRealm realm, Integer tenantId)
            throws UserStoreException {
        super(realmConfig, properties, claimManager, profileManager, realm, tenantId, false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doAuthenticate(String userName, Object credential) throws UserStoreException {

        System.out.println("TRYING TO LOGIN HERE ");

        if (CarbonConstants.REGISTRY_ANONNYMOUS_USERNAME.equals(userName)) {
            log.error("Anonymous user trying to login");
            return false;
        }

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
        String sqlstmt = null;
        String password = (String) credential;
        boolean isAuthed = false;

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            //paring the SELECT_USER_SQL from user_mgt.xml
            sqlstmt = realmConfig.getUserStoreProperty(JDBCRealmConstants.SELECT_USER);

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug(sqlstmt);
            }

            prepStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlstmt);
            prepStmt.setString(1, userName);

            rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                String storedPassword = rs.getString(2);
                if ((storedPassword != null) && (storedPassword.trim().equals(password))) {
                    isAuthed = true;
                }

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new UserStoreException("Authentication Failure. Using sql :" + sqlstmt);
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtil.closeAllConnections(dbConnection, rs, prepStmt);
        }

        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("User " + userName + " login attempt. Login success :: " + isAuthed);
        }

        return isAuthed;

    }

    @Override
    public Date getPasswordExpirationTime(String userName) throws UserStoreException {
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isValueExisting(String sqlStmt, Connection dbConnection, Object... params)
            throws UserStoreException {
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        boolean isExisting = false;
        boolean doClose = false;
        try {
            if (dbConnection == null) {
                dbConnection = getDBConnection();
                doClose = true; //because we created it
            }
            if (DatabaseUtil.getStringValuesFromDatabase(dbConnection, sqlStmt, params).length > 0) {
                isExisting = true;
            }
            return isExisting;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            log.error("Using sql : " + sqlStmt);
            throw new UserStoreException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (doClose) {
                DatabaseUtil.closeAllConnections(dbConnection, rs, prepStmt);
            }
        }
    }

    public String[] getUserListFromProperties(String property, String value, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        return new String[0];
    }


    /*@Override
    public Map<String, String> doGetUserClaimValues(String userName, String[] claims,
                                                    String domainName) throws UserStoreException {
        return new HashMap<String, String>();
    }*/

    /*@Override
    public String doGetUserClaimValue(String userName, String claim, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        return null;
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean isReadOnly() throws UserStoreException {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void doAddUser(String userName, Object credential, String[] roleList,
                          Map<String, String> claims, String profileName,
                          boolean requirePasswordChange) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    public void doAddRole(String roleName, String[] userList, org.wso2.carbon.user.api.Permission[] permissions)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteRole(String roleName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteUser(String userName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBulkImportSupported() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateRoleName(String roleName, String newRoleName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateUserListOfRole(String roleName, String[] deletedUsers, String[] newUsers)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateRoleListOfUser(String userName, String[] deletedRoles, String[] newRoles)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSetUserClaimValue(String userName, String claimURI, String claimValue,
                                    String profileName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doSetUserClaimValues(String userName, Map<String, String> claims,
                                     String profileName) throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteUserClaimValue(String userName, String claimURI, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doDeleteUserClaimValues(String userName, String[] claims, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateCredential(String userName, Object newCredential, Object oldCredential)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    @Override
    public void doUpdateCredentialByAdmin(String userName, Object newCredential)
            throws UserStoreException {
        throw new UserStoreException(
                "User store is operating in read only mode. Cannot write into the user store.");
    }

    public String[] getExternalRoleListOfUser(String userName) throws UserStoreException {
        /*informix user store manager is supposed to be read only and users in the custom user store
          users in the custom user store are only assigned to internal roles. Therefore this method
          returns an empty string.
         */

        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String[] doGetRoleNames(String filter, int maxItemLimit) throws UserStoreException {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doCheckExistingRole(String roleName) throws UserStoreException {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doCheckExistingUser(String userName) throws UserStoreException {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public org.wso2.carbon.user.api.Properties getDefaultUserStoreProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setMandatoryProperties(CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES.toArray
                (new Property[CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_MANDATORY_PROPERTIES.size()]));
        properties.setOptionalProperties(CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES.toArray
                (new Property[CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_OPTIONAL_PROPERTIES.size()]));
        properties.setAdvancedProperties(CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES.toArray
                (new Property[CustomUserStoreConstants.CUSTOM_UM_ADVANCED_PROPERTIES.size()]));
        return properties;
    }
}

@Component(
        name = "com.wso2.carbon.custom.user.store.manager",
        immediate = true

)
public class CustomUserStoreMgtDSComponent {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomUserStoreMgtDSComponent.class);
    private static RealmService realmService;

    @Activate
    protected void activate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
        try {
            CustomUserStoreManager customUserStoreManager = new CustomUserStoreManager();
            ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService(UserStoreManager.class.getName(), customUserStoreManager, null);
            log.info("CustomUserStoreManager bundle activated successfully..");
        } catch (Throwable storeError) {
            log.error("ERROR when activating Custom User Store", storeError);
        }
    }

    @Deactivate
    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
        System.out.println(" !!! DEACTIVATE COMP !!!");
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Custom User Store Manager is deactivated ");
        }
    }

    @Reference(
            name = "RealmService",
            service = org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service.RealmService.class,
            cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY,
            policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
            unbind = "unsetRealmService")
    protected void setRealmService(RealmService realmService) {
        realmService = realmService;
    }

    protected void unsetRealmService(RealmService realmService) {
        realmService = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The class you have given is a class related to constants it has very few to do with the issue you are facing. It would be fine if you can attach the whole code of your custom component. Also please specify your use case of using the custom user store manager rather than the in built JDBC user store manager

Comment: have edited and added the code as well,,, my use case is to have a custome secondary user store,,,,and users shud be able to login from my usertable,,hence created a custom userstore,,,